# Getting data from xml by attribute vlaue

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have a file with the following content (myfile.xml). I have to get all content coming under (including product node) a product with `id=1`.

```
<products>  
  <product id="1">
       <category>q</category>  
  </product>    
  <product id="2">      
       <category>w</category>    
  </product>   
  <product id="3">       
  <category>e</category>   
 </product>
</products>`
```

i.e. the result should be :

```
 <product id="1"> 
      <category>q</category>
  </product>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: follow-up [using Xmltextreader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680553/getting-data-from-xml-by-attribute-value-c-sharp-using-xmltextreader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var root = XElement.Load("path to the file");
var node = root.Descendants("product").FirstOrDefault(e=>e.Attribute("id").Value == "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

using [XPath in Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx)

```
var root = XElement.Load("myfile.xml");  
root.XPathSelectElements( "/products/product[@id=1]");
```